# Java OutOfMemory Heap Space

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-memory

everyone. I am working on a project. Along the way, I got the "OutOfMemory" problem with this line of code...

```
this.A = new int[n][n];
```

...for n =  10000;

I tried fixing it by adding `-Xmx2048m` command but the thing is when added, all of the rest of running programs stops responding. Any other suggestion for my case? Thanks a lot

Comment: Try getting a better computer?

Comment: How much physical RAM does your computer have?

Comment: 10,000 squared is 100,000,000. That makes an estimated 400 MB array size, still much lower than your 2 GB heap limit. Seems like you have other memory issues as well.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: What was your original setting for `-Xmx`?

Comment: Are you sure the heap size is set correctly? When i run your code with the default heap size, I get an `OutOfMemoryError` but setting `-Xmx2048M` it works just fine. (or any other size over 400M)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to calculate the space that array needs. If it is over 2048M then you'll receive an `OutOfMemoryError`.

In your case you try to allocate an array of `10000 x 10000` which is `100.000.000`.

A primitive `int` occupies `4` bytes. This means that the whole array takes

`100.000.000 * 4` bytes which is `0,37 GB` of space.

So it seems that there is something else in your program which caueses the error. For example if you try to allocate multiple arrays in a loop then you can run out of memory real quick.

It can be a problem if your hardware does not have `2048M` of memory.

It is also possible that before using `-Xmx2048m` you had for example `-Xmx512m` which might be too small for your array.

Comment: Do you want to say a few words about why 2048M specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

[Increase heap size in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java)

```
-Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
-Xss<size>        set java thread stack size
```

java -Xms16m -Xmx64m ClassName

Comment: Try to change the number to 1000 and see if this is your problem

Answer (score 0):

Let's see...

An `int` occupies 32bit or 4 bytes in memory. 
Your 2-dimensional array thus requires
10000 * 10000 * 4 bytes = 400000000 bytes = **381.47 MB** 
(plus storage for the array objects)

Let's verify that with a simple test:

```
int n = 10000;
int[][] foo = new int[n][n];
System.out.println("USED MEMORY: " + (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()) / 1024 / 1024);
```

Result: 384 MB (on my machine, your results may vary).

Running out of memory in the heap happens when a requested block of memory cannot be allocated, **not necessarily when the memory is full**.

As you allocate memory in blocks of 40'000 bytes, you can run out of memory when no     **contiguous free memory** of that size is available (hundreds of blocks with less that 40'000 won't help here). That means you can easily run out of **memory when the free memory on the heap is fragmented as small memory blocks**.

If you happen to allocate that memory multiple times in a row, try **reusing the allocated memory** instead of allocating it again (to prevent fragmentation to a certain degree).
Alternatively, try using smaller arrays (even if it means using more of them).